# Having a nested pop-up open and close with buttons

Tags: javascript, popup, nested

I'm trying to have multiple pop-ups in a page using two jquery functions. One of them is a button that opens up the pop-up (which is nested inside the button itself, to make it easy to position the pop-up next to the button). The other function is a button that should close the pop-up (which is inside the nested div).

Problem is, the div which makes up the first button extends it's functionality to the opened pop-up, effectively making it so that every time I want to close the pop-up, it opens up again. (or at least that's what I think it does, because after I un-nested the open button from the pop-up, the thing started working)

Here's the code for the javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$(".button_open").click(function()
{
$(this).children().css("display","inline");
});

$(".button_close").click(function()
{
$(".pop-up").css("display","none");
});

});
```

Html

```
<div class="button_open">
 <div class="pop-up">
  <div class="button_close">X</div>
Text
 </div>
</div>
```

The page will have multiple pop-ups each containing different stuff, and if possible, I'd want to have those two functions perform all the open/close stuff, instead of having a ton of functions.

So basically I'd like to know if there's any way of making the close button function inside the nested div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a click on your close-button - you make a click on the parent also. 
Try to make your code so:

```
$(".button_close").click(function(event)
{
    $(".pop-up").css("display","none");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

stopPropagation function prevents bubbling of the event to the parent. Then it should not bubble to the parent and should not cause fireing of click on the parent. Please let me know if it doesn't help.